# How to care for this plant

Tags: identification, houseplants, plant-care

I have a potted plant in my house that needs come care (especially after my cat tried to eat it); but I don't know what plant it is, or what type of environment this plant needs.

Right now, I keep it out of direct sunlight and water it with small amounts a couple of times a week (keeping the soil between somewhat-dry and not-super-wet). It used to be in a hard to reach place (cat-reasons) but that wasn't a good spot (hard to water, couple of hours of direct sunlight) and half of the plant died.

I've put it on a shelf on a small wall between two windows so it gets indirect sunlight during the day (first from one side and then from the other), and while it did recover I don't actually know anything about this plant.[image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a species of genus Philodendron. They make excellent, low light house plants, and your plant should recover. This genus of plants is very large, so exact identification is not possible, however, an helpful Wikipedia link which includes some growing and cultural information is provided below.

You should also be aware that some species of Philodendron are poisonous to cats and dogs due to concentrated Oxalate compounds they may contain.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philodendron

https://www.petpoisonhelpline.com/poison/philodendron/